# How to ask a question on Quora?

Tags: quora

[Quora](http://quora.com) seems to be a question/answer site, but browsing through the website, I don't see *any* way to ask questions at all:

[image]

I don't have a "Write Menu" which [Robert seems to have](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/29042/10579#comment22552_29042).

How do we ask a question on Quora?

Comment: Erm... From the **Write** menu, **Add Question**?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, there isn't a "Write" menu.

Comment: Then you're not logged in.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sounds like it's time to post an answer. ;)

Comment: @RobertHarvey, of course I'm logon.. http://screenshoot.me/jXWAYu

Comment: Well, it's above my pay grade then.  I have a "Write" menu, and my account is brand new.  You're not banned, are you? :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey, of course not, I haven't done anything at all on Quora.

Comment: http://screenshoot.me/03ZKhg

Comment: @RobertHarvey, how did you get that?

Comment: I created a name/password account, and logged in.  I don't have Twitter or Facebook; I prefer rocks and sticks.

Comment: @Pacerier what Robert said is true. I just created my account without using Twitter or Facebook (but using social network account, should be the same too). I did can see same screen like Robert. I found that your screen UI is quite different from our.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.quora.com/Quora-product/How-can-you-add-a-new-question?share=1 :

> To add a question generally, type your question into the "Search
>   Questions, Topics, and People" bar at the top of the page, then click
>   on "Add Question." A dialog will appear asking for question details
>   and privacy settings. Once you are done filling those out, click "Add
>   Question" in the dialog to submit the question.
>
> You can also add questions from a topic page. Find the bar that says
>   "Find or Add a Question." When you click the "Add" button from that
>   bar, again a dialog will appear asking for question details and
>   privacy settings. Click "Add Question" to submit the question.

You can also go to https://www.quora.com/question/add directly.